# Restringir um código do R a uma certa máquina local

Tags: r

Alguém sabe se é possível restringir a execução de um determinado código criado no R a uma certa máquina local? Se sim, qual seria o código?

Answer (score 3):

O comando `Sys.info()` retorna informações do sistema, entre elas, o nome da máquina na rede (`nodename`).

```
    Sys.info()
#                         sysname                      release 
#                       "Windows"                      "7 x64" 
#                         version                     nodename 
#    "build 7601, Service Pack 1"                "TBRDBZVRLZ1" 
#                         machine                        login 
#                        "x86-64"                     "tbrvlj" 
#                            user               effective_user 
#                        "tbrvlj"                     "tbrvlj"
```

Com este comando você pode identificar o `nodename` e incluir uma condicional no seu código:

```
nname <- Sys.info()['nodename']

if(nname == 'TBRDBZVRLZ1') {

  print("executa o código")

} else {

  print("não executa o código")

}
#    [1] "executa o código"
```

Comment: É bom notar que essa solução não é segura. É só a pessoa abrir o código e trocar o nome da máquina para voltar a funcionar.

Comment: @DanielFalbel, qual a alternativa mais segura?

Comment: Não existe uma solução segura se você tiver que passar o código .R para ser executado pelo cliente.. Com um pouco de conhecimento ele sempre pode alterar o código e desativar essas proteções. A solução segura é você ficar com o controle do servidor que executa o código - ex desenvolver uma API ou app.